# Angularjs filter not working on value coming from ng-if condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

i am using angularjs searchbox with `ng-model` to use this as a search value for my rendered table.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="transSearch">
```

This is my table code

```
<tbody>
    <tr dir-paginate="item in transactions | filter: transSearch | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage" data-pending-success="item.status">
        <td><div class="checkbox"><label><!--<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck">--> {{item.txn_id}}</label></div></td>
         <td>{{item.client_txn_id}}</td>
         <td>{{item.name}}</td>
         <td>{{item.phone_no}}</td>
         <td>{{item.datetime | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
        <td>{{item.amount}}</td>
        <td>{{item.client_cut}}</td>
        <td><span ng-if="item.status=='1'">Success</span><span ng-if="item.status=='0'">Pending</span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

You can see in the table in last `<td>` i am using `ng-if` to render only one value according to data i will get but this is creating problem with my filter. My finter is working in all the fields but when i am trying to filter throught last cell content its not working.

What am i missing to let filter work on the elements rendering with `ng-if`

Comment: instead of changing the complete span you can try this `<td>{{item.status == '1' ? "Success" : "Pending" }}</td>`

Comment: What about wrapping the `ng-if`s around two `<td>`, rather than inside?

Comment: @JunaidSalaat its still not working

Comment: Just as a test, could you replace `ng-if` with `ng-show`?

Comment: Perhaps the filter doesn't work because of the `<span>` tags in the `<td>`, which is why I suggest trying `<td ng-if="...">Success</td><td ng-if="...">Pending</td>`

Comment: @Corporalis tried..not working

Comment: @KScandrett nice try but this is also not working

Comment: Do you want to post a plunk?

Comment: Silly question I'm sure but do you have enough `td`s in `thead`? If @JunaidSalaat suggestion didn't work then the problem doesn't seem to be in `tbody`. It sounds like the table filter is ignoring that column regardless.

Comment: ... and could there be any attributes on the header `td` that might tell the filter to disregard that column

Comment: @KScandrett thanks for the efforts i found a solution and posted an answer.

Comment: Good answer. I'd upvote but I've reached my limit

Answer (score 0):

Model will destroy in ng-if , you can use ng-show or there is one more solution below..

You could add another directive to the same element as the one you're setting ng-if on, which deletes the property from the scope on $destroy:

**Directive**

```
myModule.directive('destroyY', function(){
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
      if(scope.form.y) delete scope.form.y;
    }) 
  }
});
```

**View**

```
<input ... data-ng-if="form.x>5" destroy-y .../>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZWoc2HmMTWvkB4ZCkOQC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the efforts but i found a better solution.

I found that angular filter will work only on the values rendering through variables defined in angular and this is also a problem that `ng-if` will destroy `ng-model` so filter will not work in my situation.

So i am checking the values through `ng-if` in controller only

```
api.getData('/wibmo/transactions/'+sessionStorage.client_id,header,'',function(error,data){
    console.log(error,data);
    if(data)
    {
        $scope.transactions = data.result.entities;
        $scope.showLoader = false;
        $scope.transactions.forEach(function(item,index){
            if(item.status=='0'){
                $scope.transactions[index].status = 'Pending'
            } else {
                $scope.transactions[index].status = 'Success'
            };
        });
    }

});
```

In this code i am overwriting the data i am getting through the api and in my html i am just printing the values like this

```
<tr dir-paginate="item in transactions | filter: transSearch | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage" data-pending-success="item.status">
    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><!--<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck">--> {{item.txn_id}}</label></div></td>
     <td>{{item.client_txn_id}}</td>
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
     <td>{{item.phone_no}}</td>
     <td>{{item.datetime | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
    <td>{{item.amount}}</td>
    <td>{{item.client_cut}}</td>
    <td>{{item.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

Its working perfectly fine now. Thanks!